# Why am I unable to open any SSL-enabled web sites in Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, fedora

I use fedora and cannot surf to SSL sites using Google Chrome.

The site is not loaded - no error message. I can surf to non-SSL sites in Chrome, and can surf to both SSL and non-SSL sites in Firefox.

EDIT: this seems to be something more general to the fedora environemtn as some other interactions with ssl via command line fail too. for example when I use npm (node.js package manager) I need to change the registry to non-ssl

EDIT2: the problem only happens when I'm behind a firewall (and have http proxy configuration). however even inside the firewall firefox works great so I still don't see what is causing this.

Comment: is it chrome (from google) or chromium (from fedora 3rd party repo)? what other "interactions" do not work? does firefox incur in the same issue? which releases of fedora and chrome?

Comment: @guido - chrome from google. "npm install" command line also does not work unless I set the registry to non ssl (npm is node.js package manager). firefox works without any problem with ssl. fedora v16, chrome v18.0.1025.162. also see my latest edit. thanks!

Comment: check if your npm problem is this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9626990/receiving-error-error-ssl-error-self-signed-cert-in-chain-while-using-npm ; and try chromium from here http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Chromium ; cannot help any more without more info

Answer (score 2):

I have had the same issue. In the error message, Chrome was informing me I was presenting a certificate that did not existed yet, with the time of my computer printed out. It turned out I messed up with the `sync` command line trying to solve a suspend/resume issue, and the time of my laptop was back to 2008. Setting back the date to today's time solved it.

I hope this helps.

Comment: This is not working for me